# Custom error message not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to get a custom error message from my CustomForm.class.php that there's in app/module/modulename/lib but someway I get another one (maybe the default from Base??)...it's like the original message error cannot be overwritten...

BaseClientForm.class.php

```
abstract class BaseClientForm extends BaseFormDoctrine
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'phonenumber'           => new sfWidgetFormInputText()
    ));

    $this->setValidators(array(

      'phonenumber'           => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 20))
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('client[%s]');

    $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

    $this->setupInheritance();

    parent::setup();
  }

  public function getModelName()
  {
    return 'Client';
  }

}
```

In ClientForm.class.php:

```
class ClientForm extends BaseClientForm {

    public function configure() {

        $this->validatorSchema['phonenumber'] = new sfValidatorAnd(array(new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 9, 'max_length' => 9, 'required' => true),array('min_length' => 'Mínimo 9 caracteres', 'max_length' => 'Máximo 9 caracteres', 'required' => 'Obligatorio')), new sfValidatorRegex(array('pattern' => '([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])','must_match' => true))));

    }
}
```

In my template:

```
<?php if($form['phonenumber']->hasError()): ?>
 <p class="error"><?php echo $form['phonenumber']->getError()->getMessage() ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Result:

```
Required
```

Why does it display "Required" if I've just changed it to "Obligatorio"? Any solution to this?

Comment: The others defined validations (min_length, max_length) are properly working?

Comment: They appear like this: "Minimo 9 caracteresRequired"

Answer (score 0):

So, debugging the framework I realised you have to pass the `required` message to your `sfValidatorAnd`:

```
$this->validatorSchema['phonenumber'] = new sfValidatorAnd(array(
            new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 9, 'max_length' => 9), array('min_length' => 'Mínimo 9 caracteres', 'max_length' => 'Máximo 9 caracteres')), 
            new sfValidatorRegex(array('pattern' => '([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])','must_match' => true))
        ), array(), array('required' => 'My required message'));
```

Also, by default all your fields are `required`, so is not necessary to explicitly declare a field `required`.

Comment: Still doesn't work...And sorry, the message that appears in the others validators are "Message Invalid" (ex: "Minimo 9 caracteres Invalid"), not "Required" like I said before

Comment: It worked for me when I tested it. Are you getting the original message with my code?

Comment: Yup, It keeps getting that "Invalid" at the final of the customized message :(

Comment: Can you share me your full from implementation with my solution?